# Clock shows incorrect time

Tags: clock

Please someone tells me why, after installing Ubuntu 12.04, that my clock displays the incorrect time. My operating system time is delayed several hours, and I don't know how to fix it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

First select your location and set your system time manually correctly or auto update from internet,

[image]